# SQL Server Management Studio installation redirected to SQL Server Installation

Tags: sql-server

After having installed SQL Server 2012 on my Windows 7 from this link:

[https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29062][1]
(ENU\x86\SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU.exe)

I downloaded SQL server Management Studio from this link:[1]: https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=29062
(ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe)

And when i start the installation, after extracting the files, it is asked if i want to allow Sql Server to make changes to my computer, i press yes, and then the SQL Server Installation Center is launched...

I don't understand what to do next, is it a current problem ?

Thank you for your attention.

Aurel

Comment: When you get to select what to install you just select Management studio and not the database engine.

Comment: @SQLChao Thank you but when the SQL Server Installation Center appears i just have 2 propositions in the "installation" menu: "New SQL Stand-alone installation" OR "upgrade from SQL Server 2005 etc."

Answer (score 1):

Using the second link you provided after you press download make sure you select this option:

[image: Sql server management studio 2012]

If you have 32 bits, then simply scroll down you will find the 32 bits exe

[image]

Comment: @Iloiacono Thanks but i have a Windows x32 bits version, so i choose ENU\x86\SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU.exe

Comment: @Iloiacono It does not help me at all, i already did what you suggest, read my post please

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the file to see what you are seeing.

Choose: `New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation.`

This will start the setup and take you to where you can select the features. You need `Management Tools - Basic`.

[image]